# What is the best open source software to store and access data from 1MB to 10GB size key-value-based?

Tags: caching, filesystems, storage, large-data, key-value-store

I'm searching for an open source software to store data from 1MB to 10GB key-value-based? In average an entry will have a size of 500MB.

It should run in a Docker container with a mounted volume as storage. Of course, it should be performant and efficient.

I found many key-value-stores, likes Redis, memcached etc. which do not support such big values? Same with MongoDB and GridFS.

Any ideas?

I googled it but did not find the right storage.

Comment: For 10 GB values you are looking for a file server, not a database, the database should only have the name and path of the file, you should probably use something like redis up to say 500 MB values and delegate the rest to a file server.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Thank you! Do you mean, I have to use an additional database for data entries > 512MB to store the key/value pairs where the values are always the path of the large files in file system?

Comment: i would probably store everything on the file server and have redis only store their paths, as you say the average is about 500 MB and even storing that on redis is going to be slow, a file server with multithreaded reads and writes is going to perform better on average for such sizes, except for things below maybe 10 MBs, but all of that greatly depend on the used hardware